# ncurses print in new color without changing the previous printed text

Tags: c, ncurses

How can I use ncurses to print some text with a new color pair, but without changing the colors of previously printed text?

```c
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("Red text + Green back\n");
    refresh();
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_WHITE);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("Green text + white back\n"); //previously printed text also change to this new color
```

Comment: `init_pair(1,` so pick a new pair, not the old one

Comment: @KamilCuk This does solve the problem but what if I constantly changing colors, then I will need to increment the index which may exceeds a maximum if reusing the pair for a new pair is not possible. I am thinking of make a hash table to cache up color pairs and retrieve the index, does this sound good? Or you have some better solution

Comment: `does this sound good?` Yes. It's possible to reuse the pair, but then the text that was drawn with that pair is changing color to the new setting.

Comment: The manual page for [`init_pair`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_pair) explains what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's old, but hope to help someone.

```c
    initscr();
    start_color();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("Red text + Green back\n");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
 
    init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_WHITE); // changed id of pair
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    printw("Green text + white back\n");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));

    refresh(); // move refresh to the end so both text will be printed
```